# Some confusion regrading $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\mathcal{B}$ a collection of subsets
>   of $X$. Then there exists a smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$ containing $\mathcal{B}$.

What I have trouble reconciling, is that I understand a $\sigma$-algebra to be a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying certain properties (i.e. it is a collection of *measurable* sets). So, what if for example $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of non-measurable sets? Then, I assume, there is no $\sigma$-algebra containing the sets from $\mathcal{B}?$

Comment: Perhaps the definition should include "$B$ is a collection of measurable subsets..."

Comment: No, measurable sets are defined as the elements of a sigma-algebra hence you are taking things in the wrong order. A priori, a sigma-algebra is just a collection of subsets of X which is stable by the operations you know. And for every collection of subsets of X there is always a sigma-algebra which contains it, namely, the sigma-algebra 2^X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be measurable is a relative notion : you are measurable for a specific $\sigma$-algebra. You seem to be confused and to think that being measurable is an internal property...measurability is defined after having defined a $\sigma$-algebra

So, if you have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B_1}$, you can take a collection of non-measurable set (for $\mathcal{B_1}$) and consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B_2}$ generated by this collection. Then your sets will be measurable for the new $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B_2}$ BY DEFINITION of measurability. This is just that $\mathcal{B_2}$ has no reason to be included in $\mathcal{B_1}$

On the other hand, if you take a collection of measurable (still for $\mathcal{B_1}$) sets as a generator, then you will indeed create a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B_1}$. But this is not the case in general

Answer (score 0):

The notion 'measurable' only has a meaning *with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra* or a *measure* (which has a $\sigma$-algebra as its domain). 
(If no $\sigma$-algebra is mentioned, then 'measurable' usually means that 'measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure' on $\Bbb R^n$, if I remember correctly.)

And, a subset $S$ is measurable w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, by definition, iff $S\in\mathcal A$.

For the proof, consider the intersection of *all $\sigma$-algebras* that contain $\mathcal B$. (Note that the whole powerset, $P(X)$ is such.).